# Почему нельзя использовать в аргументах шаблонов сущности с внутренней компоновкой?

Tags: c++

Почему нельзя использовать в аргументах шаблонов сущности с внутренней компоновкой?

```
template<char const *str>
class Template { ... };
Template<"literal"> T;            // Ошибка!
```

Нельзя использовать и глобальный указатель:

```
template<char const *str>
class Template { ... };
char const *s = "Literal";
Template<s> T;                    // Ошибка!
```

Интересуют физические причины этих ограничений, а не правила, как можно а как нельзя.

Comment: С внутренней компоновкой можно использовать, нельзя без компоновки. Проблема Вашего кода в использовании строковых литералов в качестве параметра шаблона. На этот счёт можете почитать дискуссию в С++ [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39804539#39804539).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В первом случае использование невозможно, так как даже одинаковые строковые литералы не обязаны иметь одинаковые адреса в программе. Т.е. `Template<"literal">` мог бы получать разный аргумент шаблона в зависимости от контекста (если бы это было разрешено). Более того, в черновике стандарта N4687 использование строковых литералов явно запрещено в шаблонах 17.3.2/2:

> For a non-type template-parameter of reference or pointer type, the
>   value of the constant expression shall not refer to (or for a pointer type, **shall not be the address of**):
>
> - a subobject (4.5),
> - a temporary object (15.2),
> - **a string literal** (5.13.5),

Это касается как непосредственного указания литерала, так и переменной типа `char const *` (см. далее).

---

Во втором случае ошибка из-за использования переменной, а не адреса, фиксированного на момент компиляции. Например, *gcc* даёт следующую ошибку:

> error: 's' is not a valid template argument because 's' is a variable, not the address of a variable

Чтобы всё же использовать шаблон, можно [заменить указатель массивом](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JOZoqBaSQgl5SNfq):

```
const char s[] = "literal";
Template<s> T;
```

Внутренняя или внешняя компоновка (*linkage*) будет - не важно по современным меркам, главное, чтобы она была, т.е. нельзя, например, [использовать локальные объекты](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tUKZrprvWLQNyxsH):

```
template<char const *str>
class Template { };

const char i[] = "literal"; // internal linkage
char e[] = "literal"; // external linkage

int main() { 

    char n1[] = "literal"; // no linkage
    const char n2[] = "literal"; // no linkage
    constexpr char n3[] = "literal"; // no linkage

    Template<i> Ti; // ok
    Template<e> Te; // ok

    Template<n1> Tn1; // error
    Template<n2> Tn2; // error 
    Template<n3> Tn3; // error 
}
```

Comment: "В первом случае использование невозможно, так как даже одинаковые строковые литералы не обязаны иметь одинаковые адреса в программе" - почему адреса должны быть одинаковые. "Во втором случае ошибка из-за использования переменной, а не адреса, фиксированного на момент компиляции" - тоже не понятно.

Comment: @StanislavPetrov обновил ответ.